# How to read/pass vercel system enviroment variables to code in Sanity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, vercel, sanity

I want to pass the `VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF` variable to my javascript bundle. I've deployed Sanity in Vercel and it only passes variables with the prefix `SANITY_STUDIO_`.

So, I've created an environment variable named `SANITY_STUDIO_VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF` and want to pass VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF into it.

I tried a few ways but it doesn't seem to work!

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can map environment variables by creating a `.env.production` file.

```
SANITY_STUDIO_VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF=${VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT}
```

https://www.sanity.io/docs/studio-environment-variables#f5e9e3158896